# writing RAW files with Core Graphics

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

Gentelmen, 
  is there is any possibility to write photos in RAW format? I especially interested in `com.cannon.cr2-raw-image` UTI type.

`CGImageDestinationCreateWithData` returns `<Error>: CGImageDestinationCreate type doesn't support writing` for given UTI.

Can i install some additional codecs? May be some special library, even not CoreGraphis or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled the company's domain name. The company's name is “Canon”, like the religious or literary or musical term, not “cannon”, like the naval weapon. [The correctly-spelled UTI is listed as natively supported.](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/workingwithimageio.html)

Comment: Yep, sorry for this, i wrote by memory, it is: `com.canon.cr2-raw-image`  But it doesn't change anything, it is not supported for writing, this is why i'm asking for some other library/codec or solution.  


Printing supported types for writing:


CFArrayRef types = CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers();
CFShow(types);



shows on my mac following list:
public.png, public.jpeg, com.compuserve.gif, public.jpeg-2000, public.tiff, com.adobe.photoshop-image, com.adobe.pdf, com.microsoft.bmp, com.apple.pict, com.truevision.tga-image, com.sgi.sgi-image, com.ilm.openexr-image